# Magento2: Add custom template to product details page below add to cart section

Tags: product, magento2, layout

I'm trying to add custom template to product page under social sharing section. In my module I've following code in layout file default.xml

```
 <body>
 <referenceContainer name="product.info.social">
  <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.info.custom" template="Lapisbard_Product::social.phtml" after="product.info.addtocart">
  </block>
 </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

social.phtml content

```
<p>Hey there !</p>
<?php //$_product = $block->getProduct();
```

It is working fine and showing template content on product page. When I'm using block class `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` instead of `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` so that I can get product object in my template using `$block->getProduct();`, it's showing a blank page.
 1. What mistake I'm doing here?
2. What is the best way to modify product page?
3. Is there a reference layout file which I can use to add new templates to any section of product page writing layout code in my module?

Comment: @amiteshree may be your phtml file includes functions that are defined in Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View block file

Comment: @ShaheerAli: In my phtml file I'm trying to get product object using  `$_product = $block->getProduct();` when I'm using `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` block.

Comment: Then why are you assign Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template block to your template.

Comment: That was just to check whether my template is working or not.

Comment: @amiteshree if you want to use product view functions then you need to assign Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View to your template phtml. And your method of adding custom template to product page is correct

Comment: @ShaheerAli: I've assigned same block `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` as mentioned in question. Do you have a working example of custom template file where you have got object of product?

Comment: Blank page usually means, some error happened. Did you look in your error.log? magento exceptions log? What mode do you use?

Comment: @AntonKril: I'm working in developer mode though I was not getting any error on the browser. I've got it working with the help of MauroNigrele. Thanks :)

Comment: `@amiteshree if you want to use product view functions then you need to assign Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View to your template phtml. And your method of adding custom template to product page is correct` This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The "white page" error comes because `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` have not a `getProduct()` method.

So I think that the "cleanest" way to do it is create a custom module with a custom block, layout and template *(don't worry this just take a few minutes and you have done some parts)*

Module Files:

[image]

(I will skip `/etc/module.xml` and `registration.php` because are trivial, however you could find the complete example [here](https://github.com/MauroNigrele/magento2-test-modules/tree/master/Test/Catalog).)

Let start with the Block php file:

> Test\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Extra.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\Catalog\Block\Product\View;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct;

class Extra extends AbstractProduct
{

}
```

As you can see it's just a concrete class extending (IMO) the most lightweight Product Abstract Block. You can also extend `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` but in that case you'll need to implement the `getProduct()` method and change the context in the constructor in order to get access to the registry.

So lets move to the Layout file:

> Test/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.social">
        <block class="Test\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Extra"
            name="product.view.extra"
            template="Test_Catalog::product/view/extra.phtml"
            after="-">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

And Finally the template file:

> Test/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/extra.phtml

```
<?php /* @var $block \Test\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Extra */?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct() ?>
<h3><?php echo 'My Product Name Is: ' . $_product->getName(); ?></h3>
```

As you can see is pretty straightforward, simplest than M1-

Remember that all your custom logic should be implemented in the `Extra.php` block class in order to keep the view clean.

ie:

> In the **Extra.php** class:

```
public function getSomething()
{
    return 'something'
}
```

> in the **extra.phtml** view:

```
<?php echo $block->getSomething() ?>
```

Comment: So my module's catalog_product_view.xml layout loads automatically  when I'm on product page?

Comment: Absolutly! it's very similar to M1 but now every handle is in a separated file.

Answer (score 5):

### A Supplement for the Accepted Answer

The accepted answer is good, but the `AbstractProduct` is **deprecated** now.

```
/**
 * Class AbstractProduct
 * @api
 * @deprecated 101.1.0
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NumberOfChildren)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class AbstractProduct extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
```

So, we have to use the `Magento\Framework\Registry` to achieve the **Block**, the Block sample is below:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class ProductView extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * ProductView constructor.
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     * @param Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        if ($this->product === null) {
            $this->product = $this->registry->registry('product');
        }

        return $this->product;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if its really important but PhpStorm (IDE) found 2 warnings: The use of function is_null() is discouraged; use strict comparison "=== null"() instead (in getProduct() method) AND Optional parameter is provided before required (in the constructor move $data at the end).

Comment: @urbansurfers You are right. Fix it now. Thank you!