# How to add "Buy Now" button in Magento 2.1 Product detail page along with add to cart?

Tags: magento2, cart, addtocart, magento-2.1, product-view

How to add "Buy Now" button in Magento 2.1 Product detail page along with add to cart? so the users can directly buy the product without adding into the cart.

Comment: Do you want to change "Add to cart" to "Buy now" ? assume just rename.

Comment: I want to add another button("Buy Now" button) beside "Add to cart" button. These two buttons are difference. Thanks

Comment: And what is this difference? How should we help you if you don't explain what you need?

Comment: The "Buy Now" button will redirect to check out page. I find out code for add to cart button into addtocart.phtml file: `<button type="submit"
                    title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?></span>
            </button>` .How to create a button to redirect to the check out page?

Comment: Sounds like someone is asking a question twice... http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132955/buy-now-and-add-to-cart-in-magento

Comment: @7ochem : I have used Magento 2.1. That is Magento 1.9. In Magento 2.1, how to do that?

Comment: I developed simple module to add buy now button you can download from here https://github.com/prince108/Magento2-Buynow

Comment: I developed simple module to add buy now button, download here: https://github.com/prince108/Magento2-Buynow

Comment: @Prince Patel :
I have used your module and its working on my website.  Thanks for it. but once I have checked the same with custom options of product like Size etc. It will not work. If possible can you please suggest some way.

Comment: @MinhTamPham use [this extension](https://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-2-buy-now-button.html). It works well with all custom options plus you can add the buy now button to specific products too.

Comment: @PrincePatel Sir, I am using your extension and it's working fine with simple products but facing redirection issue with configurable products. I mean when I try buy now with configurable products it's redirecting on noroute page rather than checkout page just because of product options. Sir, How can i fix it? please give me some suggestion

Answer (score 14):

Here is a module that adds a 'Buy Now' button that takes customer directly to checkout with the choosen product in cart.

Module Directory:

```
|   registration.php
|   
+---Controller
|   \---Cart
|           Add.php
|           
+---etc
|   |   module.xml
|   |   
|   \---frontend
|           routes.xml
|           sections.xml
|           
\---view
    \---frontend
        +---layout
        |       catalog_product_view.xml
        |       
        +---templates
        |       buynow.phtml
        |       
        \---web
            \---js
                    buy-now.js
```

**Add.php**

```
<?php

namespace AAllen\BuyNow\Controller\Cart;


class Add extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add
{
    /**
     * Add product to shopping cart action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
        }

        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        try {
            if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $filter = new \Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                    ['locale' => $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface')->getLocale()]
                );
                $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
            }

            $product = $this->_initProduct();
            $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

            /**
             * Check product availability
             */
            if (!$product) {
                return $this->goBack();
            }

            // empty the cart.
            $this->cart->truncate();

            $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            if (!empty($related)) {
                $this->cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
            }

            $this->cart->save();

            /**
             * @todo remove wishlist observer \Magento\Wishlist\Observer\AddToCart
             */
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                ['product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()]
            );

            if (!$this->_checkoutSession->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
                $baseUrl = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
                        ->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
                // redirect to checkout page
                return $this->goBack($baseUrl.'checkout/', $product);
            }
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            if ($this->_checkoutSession->getUseNotice(true)) {
                $this->messageManager->addNotice(
                    $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage())
                );
            } else {
                $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                foreach ($messages as $message) {
                    $this->messageManager->addError(
                        $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($message)
                    );
                }
            }

            $url = $this->_checkoutSession->getRedirectUrl(true);

            if (!$url) {
                $cartUrl = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart')->getCartUrl();
                $url = $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl($cartUrl);
            }

            return $this->goBack($url);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
            return $this->goBack();
        }
    }
}
```

**routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="buynow" frontName="buynow">
            <module name="AAllen_BuyNow"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**sections.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="buynow/cart/add">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="AAllen_BuyNow::buynow.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="AAllen_BuyNow::buynow.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**buynow.phtml**

```
<button type="submit" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Buy Now') ?>" id="buy-now" class="action buynow primary" data-mage-init='
{
    "AAllen_BuyNow/js/buy-now": {
        "form": "#product_addtocart_form"
    }
}
'>
    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Buy Now') ?></span>
</button>
```

**buy-now.js**

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    return function (config, element) {

        $(element).click(function () {
            var form = $(config.form);

            // change form action
            var baseUrl = form.attr('action'),
                buyNowUrl = baseUrl.replace('checkout/cart/add', 'buynow/cart/add');

            form.attr('action', buyNowUrl);

            form.trigger('submit');

            // set form action back
            form.attr('action', baseUrl);

            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

It works by creating a modified version of the controller used to add a product to the cart. When 'Buy Now' is clicked, the 'add product' form's action is switched to the custom controller which then redirects to the checkout page if the item is successfully added to cart.

Comment: Hey , After implement the module at magento 2 out of the box, i can see the button "Buy Now" and the buy-now.js is working after check with debug but i cant reach the BuyNow/Controller/Add.php . i try to change the xml files but still i get the core controller instead the custom one.

Comment: Hi, I made a few updates to `buy-now.js` and `Add.php`. Make those changes and try it again.

Comment: PERFECT , thank you! . By the way , where you get the information about the form action on the js? and why there is         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd" on --sections.xml-- ?

Comment: I have created module as per above layout & installed successfully, but buynow button is not showing on product page, can you please assist me for this.

Comment: Hi i follow this it's working fine but on click buy now button Add to cart change to adding then it redirect to checkout page https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269987/magento-buy-now-add-to-cart

Comment: Aaron Allen I am following solution but  getting Js issue Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined for form id

Comment: Thanks it work for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you know the basic module creation. Follow below steps:

1. Create a new module layout.

`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.social">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\Extra"
            name="product.view.extra"
            template="Vendor_Module::product/view/extra.phtml"
            after="-">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

2. Create a template file

`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/view/extra.phtml`

```
<h3><?php echo 'Custom Button'; ?></h3>
```

[Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98515/magento2-add-custom-template-to-product-details-page-below-add-to-cart-section)