# Magento 2 Buy Now Button is not there

Tags: magento-2.1

I have followed the steps suggested in

[How to add "Buy Now" button in Magento 2.1?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133154/how-to-add-buy-now-button-in-magento-2-1)

by Aaron Allen. But I couldn't see the buy now button. Could anyone guide me what I am missing ?

Here is a module that adds a 'Buy Now' button that takes customer directly to checkout with the choosen product in cart.

Module Directory:

`|   registration.php
|   
+---Controller
|   \---Cart
|           Add.php
|           
+---etc
|   |   module.xml
|   |   
|   \---frontend
|           routes.xml
|           sections.xml
|           
\---view
    \---frontend
        +---layout
        |       catalog_product_view.xml
        |       
        +---templates
        |       buynow.phtml
        |       
        \---web
            \---js
                    buy-now.js`

**Add.php**

`<?php

namespace AAllen\BuyNow\Controller\Cart;


class Add extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add
{
    /**
     * Add product to shopping cart action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
        }

        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        try {
            if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $filter = new \Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                    ['locale' => $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface')->getLocale()]
                );
                $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
            }

            $product = $this->_initProduct();
            $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

            /**
             * Check product availability
             */
            if (!$product) {
                return $this->goBack();
            }

            // empty the cart.
            $this->cart->truncate();

            $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            if (!empty($related)) {
                $this->cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
            }

            $this->cart->save();

            /**
             * @todo remove wishlist observer \Magento\Wishlist\Observer\AddToCart
             */
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                ['product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()]
            );

            if (!$this->_checkoutSession->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {

                // redirect to checkout page
                return $this->goBack('/checkout/', $product);
            }
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            if ($this->_checkoutSession->getUseNotice(true)) {
                $this->messageManager->addNotice(
                    $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage())
                );
            } else {
                $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                foreach ($messages as $message) {
                    $this->messageManager->addError(
                        $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($message)
                    );
                }
            }

            $url = $this->_checkoutSession->getRedirectUrl(true);

            if (!$url) {
                $cartUrl = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart')->getCartUrl();
                $url = $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl($cartUrl);
            }

            return $this->goBack($url);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
            return $this->goBack();
        }
    }
}`

**routes.xml**

`<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="buynow" frontName="buynow">
            <module name="AAllen_BuyNow"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>`

**sections.xml**

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="buynow/cart/add">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>`

**catalog_product_view.xml**

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="AAllen_BuyNow::buynow.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="AAllen_BuyNow::buynow.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>`

**buynow.phtml**

`<button type="submit" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Buy Now') ?>" id="buy-now" class="action buynow primary" data-mage-init='
{
    "AAllen_BuyNow/js/buy-now": {
        "form": "#product_addtocart_form"
    }
}
'>
    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Buy Now') ?></span>
</button>`

**buy-now.js**

`define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    return function (config, element) {

        $(element).click(function () {
            var form = $(config.form);

            // change form action
            var baseUrl = form.attr('action'),
                buyNowUrl = baseUrl.replace('checkout/cart/add', 'buynow/cart/add');

            form.attr('action', buyNowUrl);

            form.trigger('submit');

            // set form action back
            form.attr('action', baseUrl);

            return false;
        });
    }
});`

It works by creating a modified version of the controller used to add a product to the cart. When 'Buy Now' is clicked, the 'add product' form's action is switched to the custom controller which then redirects to the checkout page if the item is successfully added to cart.

Comment: mind showing us the code that you placed?

Comment: I developed simple module to add buy now button you can download from here https://github.com/prince108/Magento2-Buynow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I developed module to add buy now button in magento 2.

**Download here: https://github.com/prince108/Magento2-Buynow**

[image]