# How to add 'Buynow' button on product's gallery and product's detail view?

Tags: magento2.2, extensions, addtocart, custom-button, buy-now

I need to add a button for 'Buy Now / Checkout' along with the 'add to cart' button. I need to display both of these buttons together in product gallery as well as product's detail view page. I have referred some of these reference  [1]:https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-buynow

I am accessing this project through XAMPP without running apache2 or mysql services in separately. But I have installed them locally on my machine. When I follow those mentioned guidelines I am getting an error like this.

step ==> sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

**SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento2.store_website' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `store_website`.* FROM `store_website`**

I have created magento2 database in phpmyadmin and I am accessing it though phpmyadmin. So, how can I integrate this extension with my project?

Anybody can help me with this to figure it out, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many free modules available for adding Buy Now button for the products.

Please check below links:

[Link 1](https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-buynow)

[Link 2](https://www.hasotech.com/blog/magento/buy-now-button-magento2/)

If you only want to send customer directly to checkout page after clicking on Buy Now button, then you can check the [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/133692/38990) posted by Aaron Allen.

**Updated answer for the Base table or view not found error for store_website table:**

- Please check whether **`store_website`** exists or not.
- If the table does not exist, please run the following queries to create the table and fill default data:

```
CREATE TABLE store_website (
  website_id smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Website Id',
  code varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Code',
  name varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Website Name',
  sort_order smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Sort Order',
  default_group_id smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Default Group Id',
  is_default smallint(5) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Defines Is Website Default'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Websites';


INSERT INTO store_website (website_id, code, name, sort_order, default_group_id, is_default) VALUES
(0, 'admin', 'Admin', 0, 0, 0),
(1, 'base', 'Website 1', 0, 1, 1);

ALTER TABLE store_website
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (website_id),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY STORE_WEBSITE_CODE (code),
  ADD KEY STORE_WEBSITE_SORT_ORDER (sort_order),
  ADD KEY STORE_WEBSITE_DEFAULT_GROUP_ID (default_group_id);

ALTER TABLE store_website
  MODIFY website_id smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Website Id', AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
COMMIT;
```

**Updated answer for the Base table or view not found error for store_group table:**

Run the following queries in after choosing the correct database:

```
CREATE TABLE store_group (
  group_id smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Group Id',
  website_id smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Website Id',
  code varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store group unique code',
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Store Group Name',
  root_category_id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Root Category Id',
  default_store_id smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Default Store Id'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Store Groups';

INSERT INTO store_group (group_id, website_id, code, name, root_category_id, default_store_id) VALUES
(0, 0, 'default', 'Default', 0, 0),
(1, 1, 'main_website_store', 'Main Website Store', 2, 1);

ALTER TABLE store_group
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (group_id),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY STORE_GROUP_CODE (code),
  ADD KEY STORE_GROUP_WEBSITE_ID (website_id),
  ADD KEY STORE_GROUP_DEFAULT_STORE_ID (default_store_id);

ALTER TABLE store_group
  MODIFY group_id smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Group Id', AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

ALTER TABLE store_group
  ADD CONSTRAINT STORE_GROUP_WEBSITE_ID_STORE_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID FOREIGN KEY (website_id) REFERENCES store_website (website_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

**Updated answer for the Base table or view not found error for store table:**

Run the following queries in after choosing the correct database:

```
CREATE TABLE store (
  store_id smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Store Id',
  code varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Code',
  website_id smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Website Id',
  group_id smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Group Id',
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Store Name',
  sort_order smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Store Sort Order',
  is_active smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Store Activity'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Stores';

INSERT INTO store (store_id, code, website_id, group_id, name, sort_order, is_active) VALUES
(0, 'admin', 0, 0, 'Admin', 0, 1),
(1, 'default', 1, 1, 'Default Store View', 0, 1);

ALTER TABLE store
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (store_id),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY STORE_CODE (code),
  ADD KEY STORE_WEBSITE_ID (website_id),
  ADD KEY STORE_IS_ACTIVE_SORT_ORDER (is_active,sort_order),
  ADD KEY STORE_GROUP_ID (group_id);


ALTER TABLE store
  MODIFY store_id smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Store Id', AUTO_INCREMENT=2;


ALTER TABLE store
  ADD CONSTRAINT STORE_GROUP_ID_STORE_GROUP_GROUP_ID FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES store_group (group_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT STORE_WEBSITE_ID_STORE_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID FOREIGN KEY (website_id) REFERENCES store_website (website_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

**Note:** I assume that you have default Magento (with the single store setup) and there is no multi-store or multi-website setup.

Comment: Thanks. But I have already tried this Link 1 & 2 options, but the problem is  I am using Megento with XAMPP, So there was an error like  **'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento2.store_website' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `store_website`.* FROM `store_website`** . I have the database installed and I am accessing it through phpmyadmin. I s there a way to fix this?

Comment: The **`store_website`** table comes default in Magento 2. If you don't have multiple stores setup, then you can export this table from any fresh Magento 2 installation and import it into your project.

Comment: Or please update your question, so that I can post the solution for this problem. I can post correct table structure and default entries of the table.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: @SMash, please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. I have run your commands and now I am getting this error **`SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento2.store_group' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `store_group`.* FROM `store_group``** What could be the reason?

Comment: @SMash, Please check the update in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77881/discussion-between-smash-and-mohit-kumar-arora).