# "Add and checkout" button with "Add to cart" button - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

I need two buttons on product page:

- "Add to cart" - adding product to cart and staying on page
- "Buy and checkout" - adding product to cart and redirect to checkout page

I know about back-end option "After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart", but if it's turned on, redirect to checkout will be after click by any of those buttons.

Comment: Using this extension https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-buynow
Or you could see this ref https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133154/how-to-add-buy-now-button-in-magento-2-1