# Magento buy now add to cart

Tags: magento2

I followed this for buy now

Module Directory:

```
|   registration.php
|   
+---Controller
|   \---Cart
|           Add.php
|           
+---etc
|   |   module.xml
|   |   
|   \---frontend
|           routes.xml
|           sections.xml
|           
\---view
    \---frontend
        +---layout
        |       catalog_product_view.xml
        |       
        +---templates
        |       buynow.phtml
        |       
        \---web
            \---js
                    buy-now.js
```

**Add.php**

```
<?php

namespace AAllen\BuyNow\Controller\Cart;


class Add extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add
{
    /**
     * Add product to shopping cart action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
        }

        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        try {
            if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $filter = new \Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                    ['locale' => $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface')->getLocale()]
                );
                $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
            }

            $product = $this->_initProduct();
            $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

            /**
             * Check product availability
             */
            if (!$product) {
                return $this->goBack();
            }

            // empty the cart.
            $this->cart->truncate();

            $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            if (!empty($related)) {
                $this->cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
            }

            $this->cart->save();

            /**
             * @todo remove wishlist observer \Magento\Wishlist\Observer\AddToCart
             */
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                ['product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()]
            );

            if (!$this->_checkoutSession->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
                $baseUrl = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
                        ->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
                // redirect to checkout page
                return $this->goBack($baseUrl.'checkout/', $product);
            }
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            if ($this->_checkoutSession->getUseNotice(true)) {
                $this->messageManager->addNotice(
                    $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage())
                );
            } else {
                $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                foreach ($messages as $message) {
                    $this->messageManager->addError(
                        $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($message)
                    );
                }
            }

            $url = $this->_checkoutSession->getRedirectUrl(true);

            if (!$url) {
                $cartUrl = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart')->getCartUrl();
                $url = $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl($cartUrl);
            }

            return $this->goBack($url);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
            return $this->goBack();
        }
    }
}
```

**routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="buynow" frontName="buynow">
            <module name="AAllen_BuyNow"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**sections.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="buynow/cart/add">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="AAllen_BuyNow::buynow.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="AAllen_BuyNow::buynow.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**buynow.phtml**

```
<button type="submit" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Buy Now') ?>" id="buy-now" class="action buynow primary" data-mage-init='
{
    "AAllen_BuyNow/js/buy-now": {
        "form": "#product_addtocart_form"
    }
}
'>
    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Buy Now') ?></span>
</button>
```

**buy-now.js**

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    return function (config, element) {

        $(element).click(function () {
            var form = $(config.form);

            // change form action
            var baseUrl = form.attr('action'),
                buyNowUrl = baseUrl.replace('checkout/cart/add', 'buynow/cart/add');

            form.attr('action', buyNowUrl);

            form.trigger('submit');

            // set form action back
            form.attr('action', baseUrl);

            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

it working fine but on click buy now button it triger add to cart then it change adding then it redirect to Checkout

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add To Cart button is bind with form. 
When **form.trigger('submit');** this fire submit form, it will call original submit.

Open following js:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js

```
ajaxSubmit: function (form) {
    var self = this,
        productIds = idsResolver(form),
        formData;

    $(self.options.minicartSelector).trigger('contentLoading');
    self.disableAddToCartButton(form);
    formData = new FormData(form[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: formData,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,

        /** @inheritdoc */
        beforeSend: function () {
            if (self.isLoaderEnabled()) {
                $('body').trigger(self.options.processStart);
            }
        },

        /** @inheritdoc */
        success: function (res) {
            var eventData, parameters;

            $(document).trigger('ajax:addToCart', {
                'sku': form.data().productSku,
                'productIds': productIds,
                'form': form,
                'response': res
            });

            if (self.isLoaderEnabled()) {
                $('body').trigger(self.options.processStop);
            }

            if (res.backUrl) {
                eventData = {
                    'form': form,
                    'redirectParameters': []
                };
                // trigger global event, so other modules will be able add parameters to redirect url
                $('body').trigger('catalogCategoryAddToCartRedirect', eventData);

                if (eventData.redirectParameters.length > 0) {
                    parameters = res.backUrl.split('#');
                    parameters.push(eventData.redirectParameters.join('&'));
                    res.backUrl = parameters.join('#');
                }

                self._redirect(res.backUrl);

                return;
            }

            if (res.messages) {
                $(self.options.messagesSelector).html(res.messages);
            }

            if (res.minicart) {
                $(self.options.minicartSelector).replaceWith(res.minicart);
                $(self.options.minicartSelector).trigger('contentUpdated');
            }

            if (res.product && res.product.statusText) {
                $(self.options.productStatusSelector)
                    .removeClass('available')
                    .addClass('unavailable')
                    .find('span')
                    .html(res.product.statusText);
            }
            self.enableAddToCartButton(form);
        },

        /** @inheritdoc */
        error: function (res) {
            $(document).trigger('ajax:addToCart:error', {
                'sku': form.data().productSku,
                'productIds': productIds,
                'form': form,
                'response': res
            });
        },

        /** @inheritdoc */
        complete: function (res) {
            if (res.state() === 'rejected') {
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
},
```

Where changed the add to cart button text and submitted form by ajax.

```
disableAddToCartButton: function (form) {
    var addToCartButtonTextWhileAdding = this.options.addToCartButtonTextWhileAdding || $t('Adding...'),
        addToCartButton = $(form).find(this.options.addToCartButtonSelector);

    addToCartButton.addClass(this.options.addToCartButtonDisabledClass);
    addToCartButton.find('span').text(addToCartButtonTextWhileAdding);
    addToCartButton.attr('title', addToCartButtonTextWhileAdding);
},
```

Now in your controller

```
$baseUrl = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
    ->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
// redirect to checkout page
return $this->goBack($baseUrl.'checkout/', $product);
```

Which return redirected to checkout page.

[Updated]

You need to unbind form. Modify **buy-now.js** the following way:

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    return function (config, element) {

        $(element).click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            $(config.form).unbind();
            var form = $(config.form);
            // change form action
            var baseUrl = form.attr('action'),
                buyNowUrl = baseUrl.replace('checkout/cart/add', 'buynow/cart/add');

            form.attr('action', buyNowUrl);

            form.trigger('submit');

            // set form action back
            form.attr('action', baseUrl);

            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the solution on this

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: that adding should not come on click buy now

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: Also change the button type from submit to button