# Magento 2 add buy now button on product page & mini cart

Tags: addtocart, shopping-cart, product-page

I am using Magento 2.4.

I am trying to add a "buy now" button on the product & cart page, but unfortunately, when I click on the button it adds the product into the cart.
Instead of this, I would like to open a pop-up form.

Is there any way this can be implemented?
Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below links for Buy now button on the product page.

1. https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-buynow
2. [How to add "Buy Now" button in Magento 2.1 Product detail page along with add to cart?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133154/how-to-add-buy-now-button-in-magento-2-1-product-detail-page-along-with-add-to)